# Combining two inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inequality, finite-element-method

I'm having some trouble seeing how two inequalites have been combined in a proof i'm going through. The first inequlaity is

$$\| w - w_h \|_a \le \|\phi\|_{L^2}$$

and the second inequality is given by

$$\|w\|_a \le C \|\phi\|_{L^2} .$$

Which combine to give

$$\|w_h\|_a \le (C + 1) \|\phi\|_{L^2}$$

Where $w \in H^1_0$ is the solution to a PDE and $w_h$ is the finite element solution. The function $\phi \in L^2 $ has the standard $L^2$ norm and the $a$ norm is given by $\|w\|_a = \sqrt{a(w,w)}$

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit: My Attempt**

I'm not sure if this is correct,

\begin{align}
 \|w_h\|_a &= \|(-(w - w_h))+w \|_a \\
&\le \| -(w-w_h)\|_a + \|w\|_a \\
&= \| w-w_h\|_a + \|w\|_a \\ 
&\le \|\phi\|_{L^2} + C\|\phi\|_{L^2}
\end{align}

where i used the fact that for any norm $\|\alpha f\| = |\alpha| \|f\|$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It is just triangle inequality.

Comment: @geetha290krm would you be able to elaborate a bit more. I can't see how the triangle inequality is being used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the triangle inequality,

\begin{align}
 \|w_h\|_a &= \|w_h-w+w\|_a \\
&\le \| w-w_h\|_a + \|w\|_a \\
&\le \|\phi\|_{L^2} + C\|\phi\|_{L^2}
\end{align}